# How do I upgrade jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript

How do you upgrade jQuery UI in Drupal? Could this be accomplished with Composer or Drush?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update

Comment: @Kevin – Does this also upgrade jQuery UI? Or just jQuery?